# Как с помощью RxJava отправлять на сервер запрос каждые 30 секунд?

Tags: java, android, rxjava

Нужно каждые 30 секунд загружать с сервера данные и обрабатывать их определенным образом. (Используется `retrofit2` для запросов на сервер).
С отправкой одиночных запросов на сервер проблем нет, а вот как отправлять запрос каждые 30 секунд я не знаю, прошу вашей помощи.

p.s Вчера задавал такой же вопрос, отвечающий предложил реализовать это через `Service`, `BroadcastReceiver` в итоге столь невинное действие как загрузка данных с сервера каждые x секунд вылилось в несколько сотен строк кода, хотя я уверен что в `rxJava` все же это можно как то банально реализовать 1 - 2 операторами.

Comment: Можете попробовать использовать `Observable.interval` который будет выполнять нужное действие по таймингу, будет работать, пока на него кто-то подписан. Я его использовал в `Fragment`, и он работал, даже при переходе на другой фрагмент, по этому пришлось отписываться на `onDestroyView`. Правда я не уверен, что такое использование interval вообще безопасно, и скорее вызовет утечку памяти.

Comment: Вы хотите повесить фоновую задачу, выполняющую действие каждые 30 секунд, и при этом запустить ее без сервиса из активити через Rx? Плохая идея. Не заметите даже, как андроид убьет эту задачу. Ведь для чего-то созданы сервисы, а иначе просто создавали бы все из активити или application обычные треды с задачами и не парились бы. Запускаете, согласно комментарию выше, `Observable`, но в сервисе. А лучше для таких задач (экономней по ресурсам и надежней) воспользоваться FirebaseJobDispatcher.

Answer (score 1):

У вас не получится реализовать подобную задачу без сервиса. Более того, если вам необходимо гарантированно отправлять запрос и получать ответ от сервера каждые 30 секунд, вам придётся ещё и Notification в шторку повесить. Поясню:

- Android действительно достаточно принебрежительно относится ко всему, что творится в вашем приложении. То есть если не использовать Service он просто убёт то, что вы создадите из-за банальной нехватки памяти на что-нибудь ещё или потому, что ему так захотелось
- Обычный Service привязан к Activity, то есть как только умирает Activity - умирает и сервис. Тут есть пара нюансов - использование IntentService и добавление уведомления в шторку. Первое отвязывает сервис от активити, второе даёт хотя бы призрачные гарантии, что сервис не умрёт после закрытия активити
  Кроме того, можно использовать AlarmService для создания задач, повторяющихся во времени, но, как вы понимаете, к Rx это отношения не имеет.

Comment: Если обычный сервис запущен через ```startService``` то он продолжит работать после завершения активити. IntentService завершится после того как будет выполнен метод ```onHandleIntent```